# How to get value from a row using Peewee

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I have created a simple database for storing points for each user that has a unique user id (18-digit long):

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_points (
    id SERIAL,
    user_id BIGINT UNIQUE,
    points INTEGER
)
```

I want to be able to create and insert data to the specific user id by giving the user id e.g doing:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
class User(Model):
    user_id = IntegerField(column_name='user_id')
    points = IntegerField(column_name='points')

    class Meta:
        database = postgres_pool
        db_table = "user_points"

    @classmethod
    def add_points(cls, user_id):
        try:
            return (cls
                    .insert(user_id=user_id, points=10)
                    .on_conflict(
                conflict_target=[User.user_id],
                preserve=(User.user_id),
                update={User.points: User.points + 10})
                    .execute())

        except peewee.IntegrityError as err:
            logger.exception(f"{type(err).__name__} at line {err.__traceback__.tb_lineno} of {__file__}, {url}: {err}")
            postgres_pool.rollback()
            return None
```

which works fine!

And my issue is now that when I give a user id I want it to return if there is a user by that user id in the database and how many points the user has by doing

```
@classmethod
def get_user_points(cls, user_id):
    try:
        return cls.select(cls.points).where(98468376409550848 == User.user_id).get()

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        print('Doesnt exists)')
        return None

    except peewee.IntegrityError as err:
        logger.exception(f"{type(err).__name__} at line {err.__traceback__.tb_lineno} of {__file__}, {err}")
        postgres_pool.rollback()
        return None
```

[image: Database]

and using `cls.select(cls.points).where(98468376409550848 == User.user_id).get()` returns only None but it should return `70` - I wonder why and how can I be able to get points based on the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `returning` to get the ID and points:

```
iq = (cls
      .insert(user_id=user_id, points=10)
      .on_conflict(
          conflict_target=[User.user_id],
          preserve=(User.user_id),
          update={User.points: User.points + 10})
      .returning(User))
return iq.execute()[0]  # Return the user.
```

You shouldn't need to catch the integrity error above because you are explicitly telling PG what to do on conflict w/the user id.

To simply retrieve the user points by ID:

```
return User.select(User.points).where(User.user_id == user_id).scalar()
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Does it mean basically I wont need the try except at all? what about if I just want to return points?

Comment: Then you can do `.returning(User.points).tuples()` and it will return a tuple instead.